# How to set a default windows font in a paragraph using iText

Tags: java, itext

How can I set a font type by giving it's path in iText

I tried this one. But it is not working.

```
Font ff = new Font(Font.getFamily("C:/Windows/Fonts/Harry Potter Regular.ttf"));
ff.setSize(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a `BaseFont` with required font file:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(src, myEncoding, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Then create the actual font with size and style attributes, for example:

```
com.itextpdf.text.Font f = new Font(bf, 14.5f, Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD);
```

The getFamily method you used, refers to the Acrobat predefined fonts: `FontFactory.COURIER, FontFactory.HELVETICA, FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, FontFactory.SYMBOL, FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS`.

Comment: That's not entirely correct, but close enough. Either you can use the path to the Harry Potter font to create BaseFont instance and use that instance to create a Font, or you register the font in the FontFactory and you use the getFont() method with the appropriate parameters. In your code sample Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD will be ignored when using it with the 'Harry Potter Regular.ttf' because iText won't be able to find the ttfs for Bold and Italic.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your clarification. Regarding the style attributes, when I create the Font object I see they are always applied to the font specified, also it has only 1 file with the regular font.